# Running total over time period by groups in R

Tags: r

I have a customer base dataset that consists of customer ids, their subscription, and unsubscription dates. The period is from 2016-2017 and one unique customer can subscribe again to the database after an unsubscription.

I would like to count the customer growth, taking into account how many unique customers have left and come, in a monthly period. However, I'm having trouble in terms of calculating the running total for unique ids over a monthly period.

Here's the dataset that I have:

```
structure(list(country = c("US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US",
                                        "UK", "UK"), account_id = c(11L, 11L, 11L, 13L, 11L, 11L,
                                                            12L, 12L), subscribed_at = c("2017-04-25 09:01:25", "2017-04-21 09:00:24", "2017-02-19 08:09:57", "2017-01-24 16:55:56", "2016-06-27 14:00:46",
                                                                               "2016-06-27 13:55:28", "2016-08-30 10:35:29", "2016-06-28 12:35:39"
                                                            ), unsubscribed_at = c("2017-04-22 09:41:00", "2017-04-21 09:41:00",
                                                                       "2017-04-21 09:41:00", "2017-04-21 09:41:00", "2016-07-29 11:36:22",
                                                                       "2016-07-29 11:36:12", NA, NA
                                                            )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

I have used this code to clean duplicate unsubs. dates

```
dat <- dat %>%
  mutate(across(c(subscribed_at, unsubscribed_at), as.POSIXct),unsub_date = as.Date(unsubscribed_at)) %>%
  group_by(account_id, unsub_date) %>%
  mutate(unique_unsubs = if_else(row_number() %in% which.max(unsubscribed_at), unsubscribed_at, unsubscribed_at[NA])) %>%
  ungroup() 
dat <- subset(dat, select=-c(unsubscribed_at, unsub_date))
```

The desired output for IDs in US should be something like this

```
   month      running_total country
   <date>             <int> <chr>  
 1 2016-06-01             1 US     
 2 2016-07-01             0 US     
 3 2016-08-01             0 US     
 4 2016-09-01             0 US     
 5 2016-10-01             0 US     
 6 2016-11-01             0 US     
 7 2016-12-01             0 US     
 8 2017-01-01             1 US     
 9 2017-02-01             2 US     
10 2017-03-01             2 US     
11 2017-04-01             1 US
```

And what I would like to achieve is a data frame consisting of the time period and how many users were there in the base before the given time period. So one unique id subscription is counted only once until the customer unsubscribes.

What I have tried is calculating aggregated counts for unique ids per month but that caused many duplicates since if the customer is in the base in 10/2016, then the count for 11/2016 would still be 1 even though there's another subscription from the same user in 11/2016 because it's still the same customer.
Any suggestions on how should I calculate the problem?

---

Comment: Maybe try to sort by `subscribed_at` and/or `unsubscribed_at`, it's a just a vague idea

Comment: Try to provide your dataframe (or a part of it) with `dput(your_df)`

Comment: Yes, it will be more easy to help you then. Put it in your question's code please

Comment: Can you contact me on Telegram so we discuss by phone ? 
@julauto is mu username on it.
I don't think I understood the whole setting of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me know if this solution works. I pivot both subscription columns into the same column, numerically code them, make the rows distinct based on subscription, unsubscription, and resubscription, then finish with a cumulative sum.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

data <- structure(list(country = c("US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US",
                                        "UK", "UK"), account_id = c(11L, 11L, 11L, 13L, 11L, 11L,
                                                            12L, 12L), subscribed_at = c("2017-04-25 09:01:25", "2017-04-21 09:00:24", "2017-02-19 08:09:57", "2017-01-24 16:55:56", "2016-06-27 14:00:46",
                                                                               "2016-06-27 13:55:28", "2016-08-30 10:35:29", "2016-06-28 12:35:39"
                                                            ), unsubscribed_at = c("2017-04-22 09:41:00", "2017-04-21 09:41:00",
                                                                       "2017-04-21 09:41:00", "2017-04-21 09:41:00", "2016-07-29 11:36:22",
                                                                       "2016-07-29 11:36:12", NA, NA
                                                            )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L)) %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(row_num = row_number(),
         across(c(subscribed_at, unsubscribed_at), ymd_hms)) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(subscribed_at, unsubscribed_at), names_to = "subscription", values_to = "date") %>%
  mutate(date = replace_na(date, max(date, na.rm = TRUE) + dmonths(1)),
         date = date(floor_date(date, 'month'))) 

minimum_date <- min(data$date)
maximum_date <- max(data$date)

data %>%
  group_by(row_num) %>%
  complete(date = seq.Date(from = min(date), to = max(date), by = "month")) %>%
  fill(everything(), .direction = "down") %>%
  group_by(row_num) %>%
  distinct(date, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
  filter(n() != 1,
         subscription != "unsubscribed_at") %>%
  group_by(country, date) %>%
  summarise(running_total = n()) %>%
  complete(date = seq.Date(from = minimum_date, to = maximum_date, by = "month")) %>%
  mutate(running_total = replace_na(running_total, 0))
```

Comment: – Thank you very much, it seemed to work! I have another question. What if I would like to see the running total based on months and countries? So let's say I have country codes for US and CH. I would like to see the monthly running totals for each country.

Comment: That would be not easy to incorporate with this approach do to grouping/ungrouping/distinct, but provided that you only have a few countries, you could just split the tibble into multiple based on country, do this exact operation except add a country column as a very last step, then bind_rows them back together.

Comment: I'm very much new to the tibble, so how would this look in R code? If let's say the id ="123" belongs to country = "CH"

Comment: Just made the required edits! Enjoy.

Comment: Made even more edits, group_map allows you to have as many countries as you would like.

Comment: Massive thank you! How can I get the function to work for cases when there are many same date unsubscriptions for the same id? I just edited the dataset to my original question. So for id=111, the running total for 04/2017 seems to be -4, even though there is only one unsubscription but the same date is repeated 4 times. I would like to count the same unsubscription dates for each unique id only once and therefore, the running total for 04/2017 for id=111 would actually be 0.

Comment: Getting rid of the distinct line seemed to do the trick, let me know if that works with all of your data.

Comment: Thank you again! It doesn't seem to work with cases where there are two different unsubs. dates within the same month by the same ID. I have put the example dataset on my original question if you have time to look at that. Appreciate your help!

Comment: Let me know if these edits work. If not, please provide much more data with a full expected output.